# How to improve ambient occlusion in cycles, and reduce pixelation/tearing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

How can I troubleshoot cycles baking effectively, what am I missing that leads to such unusable results? 
I tried many variations with the mesh itself before switching over to blender render for a moment and baking there to see if the model was the trouble.

Blender Render AO bake
[image: AO map baked in blender render:]

The results were far far better even discounting the black spots that are always present (in the same places) in cycles renders.

Baking AO in cycles for previous models has also resulted in **consistent** black spots, seemingly unrelated to model geometry, they can happen in the middle of huge empty faces, or right next to vertices.

Cycles Render AO bake
[image: AO map baked in cycles:]

I am also experiencing some trouble with baking Diffuse Color. 
This example was baked at 1024x1024, increasing the resolution leads to more and more drastic tearing.

Cycles Render Diffuse Color bake with tearing
[image: Tearing (in diffuse color baking):]

[example blend file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzihPhAWvlgOTDdWUjRJZkVvYlU)

Comment: Very strange, never seen anything like this in any of my cycles bakes.. Is it possible you could upload a .blend?

Comment: One blend file, coming right up. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzihPhAWvlgOTDdWUjRJZkVvYlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Huh.. I really have no idea, it looks like it might be a bug. You could try reporting it on [the tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug).

Comment: I've checked the mesh for errors and can find nothing.  I separated the front and back pieces then remapped just one side so the UV's were proportional and this helped a lot but there were still some noticeable errors.  I noticed in the UV image Editor that the errors were showing up at the same spots where the drawing code was displaying the UV coord lines slightly jagged from aliasing.  This definitely looks like a bug.  If you are uncomfortable posting to the tracker, let me know and I'll submit it.  Please let me know either way, I really want to see this fixed.

Comment: Yes mark I had also noticed some correlation between uv mapping and non square lines on the uv map, but I have been unable to find a way to force it to square without manually straightening every. single. line. It took me a while to look at that aspect because in my previous model with this issue, the artifacts were appearing in the middle of very large empty faces, Then I realized that's right where the edge gets added to triangulate the quad. I would appreciate it if you would post the issue, I haven't even signed up there yet.

Comment: I tend to notice cycles rendering errors when using an orthographic projection matrix (shows up as dark edges in polygons). Could these lines be polygon edges? Because I assume that baking is orthographic.